# scrapy link extractor by value of html tag

Tags: recursion, scrapy, tags

I'm using scrapy to scrape privacy policies by crawling a website from its homepage as such, I want to intelligently crawl specific links within pages containing specific keywords (privacy, data, protection etc...).

I saw that scrapy's CrawlSpider and the [LinkExtractor](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor) object allow for just that, however I would like the [LinkExtractor](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor) to not only apply a regex to the discovered links, but also to the text within the `<a></a>` tags

In order to, for example, better identify cases like these:

```html
<a href="http://example.com/legal">Check out our privacy policy</a>
```

In which, the URL might not be a perfect match, but the text within the HTML tags is more helpful.

I saw that scrapy's LinkExtractor object already has an argument called `process_value` which can launch an operation on the text within the HTML tag, but I'm unsure how I could "return a Positive link match" (like the regex expression given in the `allow` parameter would) and thus "add this link to the list of things to parse by the CrawlSpider object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll be able to do this in Scrapy **1.7.0** or later. See [#3635](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/3635).

The changes add a `restrict_text` parameter to `LinkExtractor`. From the [master branch of the Scrapy documentation on LinkExtractor](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml):

> **restrict_text** (*a regular expression (or list of)*) – a single regular expression (or list of regular expressions) that the link’s text must match in order to be extracted. If not given (or empty), it will match all links. If a list of regular expressions is given, the link will be extracted if it matches at least one.